# how to hide filename using .htaccess , create custom username on url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, web

I want remove file name from url .

my current url is:

```
http://www.demo.com/user.php?name=joon
```

and I want to :

```
http://www.demo.com/joon
```

if I use this code

```
 RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?name=$1
```

output is

```
http://www.demo.com/user/joon
```

but I want

```
http://www.demo.com/joon
```

Comment: if you do a search for .htacess you should find plenty of resources. I know there is also some generator if you don'T want (like me) the hassle of learning this by heart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /user.php?u=$1 [L]
```

RewriteCond is important here to avoid rewriting your existent directories to /user.php.

This will rewrite **/user** to **/user.php?u=user** .

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Apache URL Rewriting. You need to make changes to your .htaccess file. This blog post covers it nicely
https://expozit.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/apache-url-shortening/